# Photoshop Artboard has a weird 1px line around?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard

Can anyone tell me why artboard in Photoshop be bounded by a 1px line. How I can fix this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: So this is CC 2015?

Comment: Hi Troy, yes I'm using CC 2015 trial before decide to tranform from CS6 to subscription mode.

Comment: Yes I have the same problem with the new Feature, you can actually move to the top over the name of the artboard

Answer (score 8):

Has this got anything to do with your preferences setup where your borders might be set to line?

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest this, yet in addition I think it assumes you will have a background too—in which case you wouldn't see that. Regardless, this is just in the UI. I don't think you need to worry.

Comment: This was annoying me so much - it actually hinders my ability to see when I have the artwork properly aligned on the artboard! So glad it was possible to remove!

Answer (score 2):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>**K**</kbd>.
- Select option *interface → artboards*, set border from *line* to *none*.
- Save the settings and you’re good to go.

Comment: You solved the Adobe's damn puzzle! Thanks for sharing! I was seeing a weird 1px border, and then I resized elements but that border was still there and I couldn't find a border on my layers and that thing was driving me to crazy. You helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If I set Preferences -> Interface -> Border to Line. The canvas now looks like this:

[image]

It's zoomed in, you can see the 1px line bounds around the artboard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the artboard by either clicking the title in the content area, or from the layers panel.
2. Right click / cmd + click and'Ungroup Artboard'

[image: example]